# ZF2 Validator File by \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http

Tags: zend-framework2

I have HTML Code 2 input file in view of a action.

```
<form action="#" id="appForm" name="appForm"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="picture" id="picture">
<input type="file" name="attach_file" id="attach_file">
</form>
```

After that, i submit this form to a action of controller. Code in action to get Post

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                    $item = array_merge_recursive($this->params()->fromPost(), $this->params()->fromFiles());
        $item['id'] = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
                    $item['action'] = 'edit';
        $validator = new ArticleValidator($item);
        if($validator->isError()) {
            $error = array_merge($error, $validator->getError());
            $item = $validator->getData();
        }else{
            echo ' save data';
            die();
        }
    }
```

And code in ArticleValidator

```
    namespace Admin\Form;

class ArticleValidator {

protected $_arrError = null;
protected $_arrData;

public function __construct($arrParam = array(), $options = null) {

    // avatar
    if (!empty($arrParam['picture']['name'])) {
        $size = new \Zend\Validator\File\Size(array('min' => 1, 'max' => 2097152));
        $ext = new \Zend\Validator\File\Extension('gif,jpg,jpeg,png');
        $adapterPicture = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
        $adapterPicture->setValidators(array($size, $ext), $arrParam['picture']['name']);
        if (!$adapterPicture->isValid()) {
            $message = $adapterPicture->getMessages();
            $this->_arrError['picture'] = current($message);
            $arrParam['picture'] = '';
        }
    }

    // attach_file
    if (!empty($arrParam['attach_file']['name'])) {
        $size = new \Zend\Validator\File\Size(array('min' => 1, 'max' => 5242880));
        $ext = new \Zend\Validator\File\Extension('rar,zip,gz,docx,pdf,xlsx');
        $adapterFile = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
        $adapterFile->setValidators(array($size, $ext), $arrParam['attach_file']['name']);
        if (!$adapterFile->isValid()) {
            $message = $adapterFile->getMessages();
            $this->_arrError['attach_file'] = current($message);
            $arrParam['attach_file'] = '';
        }
    }
}

}
```

When i post a valid image into 'picture' field. $this->_arrError will have "File '' was not uploaded". I check and know that, $adapterPicture also check 'attach_file' field. Because i do not post a file into 'attach_file', so it say not uploaded ( for attach_file).
So, how i can check only for 'picture' field and then check only for 'attach_file'.
PS: I'm not use Zend\Form. Just a HTML code with 2 input type=file. And then, check file use    \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http

Comment: Why are you not using a `Zend\Form` object?

Comment: @AlexP Because it is requirement. So, i must use only HTML, not Zend\Form.

Comment: I print it, i see that, it auto add Zend\Validator\File\Upload in each file. But i only add validator with each adapter separate. So, how validator each file with each validator